# iTextSharp with C# creating a 2 column pdf. Each column is a pdfptable and each page is filed top to bottom then left to right

Tags: c#

I'm not a java person so I'm having trouble converting the Java examples using Float and ColumnText to C#. I have a hundreds of rows of data that I need to put into a 4 column table. The pdf will need to be like a newspaper, ie fill the left column with data then the right and then move to the next page. Seems like there should be lots of examples of this but I can't seems to find any that actually work.

Thanks in advance,
--- Q

Comment: I am not following the with 4 columns and the reference to a newspaper. Should there be one table with 4 columns or two "staggered" tables with two columns on one page?

Comment: Newspaper reference is just for a visual. The pdf has 2 columns per page and each column is a table with 4 columns. Both of the columns on each page are exactly the same. Similar to this example:

Comment: Similar to the last example of chapter 4 inthe iTextSharp in Action Second Edition book. It uses ColumnText with a pdfpTable but I can't get the "float" syntax to work in C#.
Thanks

Comment: Sorry, I have not used the Float. I have just built tables for a data grid export function.